# How many ways can $2m$ be represented as the sum of 4 natural numbers $\le m$?

Tags: combinatorics

A man goes in for an examination in which there are $4$ papers with a maximum of $m$ marks for each paper.  I believe that the number of ways the man can get $2m$ marks on the entire examination is

$$\frac{(m+1)(2m^2+4m+3)}{3}$$

How can I prove this?

Comment: What is "the number of getting 2m marks on the whole"?

Comment: we have to get total marks as 2m

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a generatingfunctionological approach:

The required number is the coefficient of $x^{2m}$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^m)^4$. Now,

$$\begin{align}(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^m)^4&=(1-x^{m+1})^4(1-x)^{-4}\\
&=(1-4(x^{m+1})\cdots)(\cdots+\binom{m+2}{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+\binom{2m+3}{2m}x^{2m}+\cdots)\end{align}$$

I believe you can finish it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed formula corresponds to the sequence of [octahedral numbers](http://oeis.org/A005900).  If you label the scores on the individual papers by $w$, $x$, $y$, and $z$, then your problem is equivalent to enumerating the solutions of the equation

$$w + x + y + z = 2m$$

subject to the condition that $w$, $x$, $y$, and $z$ are all nonnegative and bounded by $m$.  This equation defines a 3-dimensional region in 4-dimensional space.  What is that region?